# What are "Activations", "Activation Gradients", "Weights" and "Weight Gradients" in Convolutional Neural Networks?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I've just finished reading [the notes](https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/) for Stanford's CS231n on CNNs and there is a link to a live [demo](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/demo/cifar10.html); however, **I am unsure by what "Activations", "Activation Gradients", "Weights" and "Weight Gradients" is referring to in the demo.** The below screenshots have been copied from the demo.

**Confusion point 1**

I'm first confused by what "activations" refers to for the input layer. Based on the notes, I thought that the activation layer refers to the RELU layer in a CNN, which essentially tells the CNN which neurons should be lit up (using the RELU function). I'm not sure how that relates to the input layer as shown below. Furthermore, why are there two images displayed? The first image seems to display the image that is provided to the CNN but I'm unable to distinguish what the second image is displaying.

[image]

**Confusion point 2**

I'm unsure what "activations" and "activation gradients" is displaying here for the same reason as above. I think the "weights" display what the 16 filters in the convolution layer look like but I'm not sure what "Weight Gradients" is supposed to be showing.

[image]

**Confusion point 3**

I think I understand what the "activations" is referring to in the RELU layers. It is displaying the output images of all 16 filters after every value (pixel) of the output image has had the RELU function applied to it hence why each of the 16 images contains pixels that are black (un-activated) or some shade of white (activated). However, I don't understand what "activation gradients" is referring to.

[image]

**Confusion point 4**

Also don't understand what "activation gradients" is referring to here.

[image]

I'm hoping that by understanding this demo, I'll understand CNNs a little more

Answer (score 5):

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38136058/6873133) question, but not quite. Also, [here's a link](https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs#example-code) to the ConvNetJS example code with comments ([here's a link](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/karpathy/convnetjs/docs.html) to the full documentation). You can take a look at the code at the top of the demo page for the code itself.

An [activation function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Activation_function) is a function that takes in some input and outputs some value based on if it reaches some "threshold" (this is specific for each different activation function). This comes from how neurons work, where they take some electrical input and will only activate if they reach some threshold.

**Confusion Point 1:** The first set of images show the raw input image (the left colored image) and the right of the two images is the output after going through the activation functions. You shouldn't really be able to interpret the second image because it is going through non-linear and perceived random non-linear transformations through the network.

**Confusion Point 2:** Similar to the previous point, the "activations" are the functions the image pixel information is passed into. A [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) is essentially the slope of the activation function. It appears more sparse (i.e., colors show up in only certain places) because it shows possible areas in the image that each node is focusing on. For example, the 6th image on the first row has some color in the bottom left corner; this may indicate a large change in the activation function to indicate something interesting in this area. This [article](https://medium.com/the-theory-of-everything/understanding-activation-functions-in-neural-networks-9491262884e0) may clear up some confusion on weights and activation functions. And [this article](https://ujjwalkarn.me/2016/08/11/intuitive-explanation-convnets/) has some really great visuals on what each step is doing.

**Confusion Point 3:** This confused me at first, because if you think about a [ReLu function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), you will see that it has a slope of one for positive `x` and 0 everywhere else. So to take the gradient (or slope) of the activation function (ReLu in this case) doesn't make sense. The "max activation" and "min activation" values make sense for a ReLu: the minimum value will be zero and the max is whatever the maximum value is. This is straight from the definition of a ReLu. <s>To explain the gradient values, I suspect that some Gaussian noise and a [bias term of 0.1](https://github.com/karpathy/convnetjs/blob/4c3358a315b4d71f31a0d532eb5d1700e9e592ee/src/convnet_net.js#L43) has been added to those values.</s> **Edit:** the gradient refers to the slope of the cost-weight curve shown below. The y-axis is the loss value or the calculated error using the weight values **w** on the x-axis.

[image]

<sub>Image source https://i.ytimg.com/vi/b4Vyma9wPHo/maxresdefault.jpg</sub>

**Confusion Point 4:** See above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this was extremely helpful and I appreciate how much time you spent writing this. Just to clarify your explanation of point 1, are you saying that the image on the right is after it has gone through the entire network? If so, I would expect the image on the right to have a far lower resolution than the original having gone through so many max-pool layers. Also regarding the "activation gradients", do you think it might actually be talking about the gradient of the error in all cases including RELU (this literally just occurred to me as I was reading your articles)?

Comment: For point 1, I'd say the image on the right only has gone through one layer of the network, namely the activation function. And ah yes, upon more thinking, I agree: the gradient is of the error profile for the ReLu. I'll update my answer above.

Answer (score 3):

**Confusion point 1:** Looking at the code it seems like in the case of the input layer the "Activations" visualisation are the coloured image for the first figure. The second figure does not really make any sense because the code is trying to display some gradient values but it's not clear where they come from.

```
// HACK to draw in color in input layer
if(i===0) {
  draw_activations_COLOR(activations_div, L.out_act, scale);
  draw_activations_COLOR(activations_div, L.out_act, scale, true);
```

**Confusion point 2, 3 & 4:**

- Activations: It is the output of the layer
- Activation Gradients: This name is confusing but it is basically the gradient of the loss with respect to the input of the current layer l. This is useful in case you want to debug the autodif algorithm
- Weights: This is only printed if the layer is a convolution. It's basically the different filters of the convolution
- Weight Gradients:It is the gradient of the loss with respect to the weights of the current layer l

Answer (score 0):

**Confusion point 1**
For Convolutional Layers, every layer has a duty to detect features. Imagine that you want to detect a human face, first layer will detect edges, maybe next layer will detect your noses and so on. Towards last layer, more complex features will be detected. In first layer, what you see is what first layer detected from image.
**Confusion point 2**
If you look through fully connnected layers, I think they probably showing up the gradients they obtained during back-propagation. Because through fully connected layers, they get only gray black etc colors. 
**Confusion point 3**
There is nothing relu layers. After convulution you use activation function, and you get another matric, and you pass it through another layer. After relu, you get the colors.
**Confusion point 4**
It is same above.

Please let me know when you don't understand any point.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. For point 1, I'm confused what "activation" means in relation to the input layer as demonstrated by the demo.

Comment: Hello again! I hope this time I will be more clear, they put a image through cnn and for the first layer they detected edges. After convulution they got first activation, probably they mean after first convulution by "activation". Because it is what they got. They just detected edges after convulution after that, thay pass through relu.